# Using React.js with Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, reactjs

I am having issues with React when using sublime text 3.
I installed proper packages for jsx, babel etc:  for some reason when I try to run a simple component I get a massive error in the console. Keep in mind I am new to react. Please help: see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>React - Template</title>
<script src="../../js/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

    var bacon = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return(<h3>This is a simple component</h3>);
 }<!--end of component-->

});

    ReactDOM.render(<bacon/>,document.getElementById('example'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR I RECEIVE IN THE CONSOLE**

```
browser.min.js:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (7:6)
   5 |         render: function(){
   6 |             return(<h3>This is a simple component</h3>);
>  7 |      }<!--end of component-->
     |       ^
   8 | 
   9 |     });
  10 | 
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.min.js:41)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.min.js:42)
    at Parser.readToken_lt_gt (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.getTokenFromCode (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.readToken (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.readToken (browser.min.js:42)
    at Parser.nextToken (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.next (browser.min.js:43)
    at Parser.eat (browser.min.js:43)
pp.raise @ browser.min.js:41
pp.unexpected @ browser.min.js:42
readToken_lt_gt @ browser.min.js:43
getTokenFromCode @ browser.min.js:43
readToken @ browser.min.js:43
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:43
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:42
nextToken @ browser.min.js:43
next @ browser.min.js:43
eat @ browser.min.js:43
pp.parseBlock @ browser.min.js:41
pp.parseFunctionBody @ browser.min.js:41
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:42
pp.parseFunction @ browser.min.js:41
pp.parseExprAtom @ browser.min.js:40
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:43
pp.parseExprSubscripts @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeUnary @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprOps @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeConditional @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeAssign @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseObjPropValue @ browser.min.js:40
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:42
pp.parseObj @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprAtom @ browser.min.js:40
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:43
pp.parseExprSubscripts @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeUnary @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprOps @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeConditional @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeAssign @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprListItem @ browser.min.js:41
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:42
pp.parseExprList @ browser.min.js:41
pp.parseSubscripts @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprSubscripts @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeUnary @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseExprOps @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeConditional @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseMaybeAssign @ browser.min.js:40
pp.parseVar @ browser.min.js:41
pp.parseVarStatement @ browser.min.js:41
pp.parseStatement @ browser.min.js:41
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:42
pp.parseTopLevel @ browser.min.js:41
parse @ browser.min.js:41
parse @ browser.min.js:40
exports.default @ browser.min.js:7
parse @ browser.min.js:7
parseCode @ browser.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:10
wrap @ browser.min.js:7
transform @ browser.min.js:10
transform.run @ browser.min.js:4
exec @ browser.min.js:4
runScripts @ browser.min.js:4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the HTML comment (`<!--end of component-->`)

Comment: @Tico, dang thank you. I am new to react... why can’t comments be used? Thank you

Comment: <!-- --> is used to comment HTML, use /**/ or // to comment JS

Comment: You're writing a JS script, so use JS comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the HTML comment (`<!--end of component-->`). Since you're writing JS code, use JS comments `/* ... */` or `//`

The console error is also very explicit about it, in time you'll get used to it!

Comment: Thanks Everyone. Appreciate the kind comments, this is literally my first react trial.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment `<!--end of component-->` is outside of the JSX and inside regular javascript. You need to use JS comment syntax such as `/*end of component*/` or `//end of component`. eg:

```
var bacon = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(<h3>This is a simple component</h3>);
  } /*comment outside the JSX*/
});
```

Note if it had been written inside the JSX, it would have still caused you problems. In that case you would still use the JS comment syntax and wrap it in brackets like this:

```
var bacon = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(<h3>
      This is a simple component
      {/*comment inside the JSX*/}
    </h3>);
  }
});
```